# Test load on Web Server

Tags: benchmark

I want to benchmark my server to the best configuration for Apache and MySql. I want you to ask if do you know any script that simulates various users browsing on the website? 
PD: I'm using Debian
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache
  Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) (AB)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a cloud solution if you're planning to stress your application to the max.
Here's why, tools which are initiated by your workstation/server are limited to your local resources.
It can't be your just producing hits to simulate traffic, you have to keep in mind that browsers open simultanious connections to your Server (i think that would be 4 up to 6, correct me if i'm wrong).

There are a few cloud-stresstesting tools and all of them got some free options, but they get expensive. It's still a got option if you want to test the scalability of your application.

Some examples of Cloud stresstools

- load impact
- loadstorm
- browsermob

and some more in depth comparision
http://www.brickyardtech.com/blog/2011/11/review-of-cloud-based-load-testing-services/